# how to create a optional list field in prisma

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, prisma

I am creating a basic crud api with nodejs and prisma. My Schema is as follows:

```js
generator client {
       provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
       provider          = "postgresql"
       url               = env("DATABASE_URL")
       shadowDatabaseUrl = env("SHADOW_DATABASE_URL")
}

  

model Category {
       id          String    @unique @default(cuid())
       title       String
       description String
       products    Product[]
}

model Product {
  id          String    @unique @default(cuid())
  title       String
  description String
  price       Float
  createdAt   DateTime  @default(now())
  updatedAt   DateTime?

  category   Category? @relation(fields: [categoryId],  references: [id])
  categoryId String?
}
```

I am trying to make the products field in the Category model optional. But Prisma doesn't allow that. But I want my users to create a category even without creating a post or vice-versa. How can I get around this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the Prisma documentation, lists cannot be optional: https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-schema-reference#remarks-5

However, the `products` field not being optional does not mean that it cannot be an empty when a new `Category` is created:

```js
await prisma.category.create({
  data: {
    title: 'books',
    description: 'books',
    products: {},
  }
})
```

Then you can create or connect the product later:

```js
await prisma.category.update({
  where: {
    id: "category-id"
  },
  data: {
    products: {
      connect: {
        id: "product-id"
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your afford. But when I am making a post request for the category. I am given a json response of `products is not defined." even if I pass a empty products: [] array. I am not sure why this is happening

Comment: Thanks a lot man. The problem is solved

Comment: @AsiefMahir did you solve like Gergely suggested or what did you do?

Comment: If you're using the generated `CategoryModel` to validate your post request 's body parameter, you can use typescript `Pick` utility type to exclude the array prop. Ex: `Pick<CategoryModel, 'title' | 'description'>`